# MVVM with ASP.NET MVC, partial class as ViewModel not performing as expected

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, mvvm

I'm using Entity Framework, and as such I don't want to put Razor validation syntax in the EF models. For that reason, I created a viewmodel that would do the validation for me, but it has since become apparent that I will need a view model that supports the object in different states. Where it was working fine, it now only validates SOME of the fields.

The two partial classes are as follows;

The Entity Framework generated model:

```
public partial class BCRTAdvisoryRequest
{
    public int RequestID { get; set; }
    [DataType(DataType.Date)]
    public Nullable<System.DateTime> DateCreated { get; set; }
    public int TeamMemberID { get; set; }
    public int RequestTypeID { get; set; }
    [DataType(DataType.Date)]
    public System.DateTime DateRequested { get; set; }
    public string SiteName { get; set; }
    public int ServiceCategoryID { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public string RequestedBy { get; set; }
    public string JobTitle { get; set; }
    public string LocalOfficeOrTeam { get; set; }
    public Nullable<bool> SiteVisit { get; set; }
    public int StatusID { get; set; }
    public Nullable<bool> ConsultantRetained { get; set; }
    public string Comments { get; set; }
    public int LastModifiedByID { get; set; }
    public System.DateTime LastModifiedDate { get; set; }

    public virtual User User { get; set; }
    public virtual BCRTAdvisoryRequestServiceCategory BCRTAdvisoryRequestServiceCategory { get; set; }
    public virtual BCRTAdvisoryRequestStatus BCRTAdvisoryRequestStatus { get; set; }
    public virtual BCRTAdvisoryRequestType BCRTAdvisoryRequestType { get; set; }
    public virtual User User1 { get; set; }
}
```

And the validation model:

```
public partial class BCRTAdvisoryRequest
{
    [MetadataType(typeof(BCRTAdvisoryRequest.MetaData))]
    public sealed class MetaData
    {
        [Display(Name = "Date Created")]
        [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:dd MMM yyyy}")]
        public System.DateTime DateCreated { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [Display(Name = "Request Type")]
        public int RequestTypeID { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [Display(Name = "Date Requested")]
        [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:dd MMM yyyy}")]
        public System.DateTime DateRequested { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [Display(Name = "Site Name")]
        public string SiteName { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [Display(Name = "Service Category")]
        public int ServiceCategoryID { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [Display(Name = "Description")]
        public string Description { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [Display(Name = "Requested by")]
        public string RequestedBy { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [Display(Name = "Job Title")]
        public string JobTitle { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "Local Office/Team")]
        public string LocalOfficeOrTeam { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "Site Visit")]
        public Nullable<bool> SiteVisit { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [Display(Name = "Status")]
        public int StatusID { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "Consultant Retained")]
        public Nullable<bool> ConsultantRetained { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "Comments")]
        public string Comments { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Now as for the behaviour, I would expect that this would be enough information for a partial view using the BCRTAdvisoryRequest class as a model to validate properly against, but apparently not.

This is what happens:

[image: Partial view with BCRTAdvisoryRequest model]

The problem with that dialog being that half the required fields aren't validated, none of the labels work ..

The partial view is coded as follows;

```
@model EH.BCRT.AdvisoryRequests.Model.BCRTAdvisoryRequest

<link href="@Url.Content("/Content/Site.css")" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="@Url.Content("/Content/themes/base/jquery.ui.dialog.css")" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="@Url.Content("/Content/themes/base/jquery.ui.datepicker.css")" rel="stylesheet" />

<form id="advisoryRequestForm">
    @using (Html.BeginForm())
    {
        @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
        @Html.ValidationSummary(true)

        <fieldset>
            <legend>BCRTAdvisoryRequest</legend>
            <div class="container">
                <div class="h-double">
                    <div class="editor-label">
                        @Html.LabelFor(m => m.RequestTypeID)
                    </div>
                    <div class="editor-field">
                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.RequestTypeID)<br />
                        @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.RequestTypeID, (IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)ViewBag.RequestTypeID, "", null)
                    </div>

                    <div class="editor-label">
                        @Html.LabelFor(m => m.DateRequested)
                    </div>
                    <div class="editor-field">
                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.DateRequested)<br />
                        @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.DateRequested, new { @class = "datepickerfield", id = ViewBag.datepickeruid })
                    </div>

                    <div class="editor-label">
                        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.SiteName)
                    </div>
                    <div class="editor-field">
                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.SiteName)<br />
                        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.SiteName)
                    </div>

                    <div class="editor-label">
                        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.ServiceCategoryID)
                    </div>
                    <div class="editor-field">
                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.ServiceCategoryID)<br />
                        @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.ServiceCategoryID, (IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)ViewBag.ServiceCategoryID, "", null)
                    </div>

                    <div class="editor-label">
                        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Description)
                    </div>
                    <div class="editor-field">
                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Description)<br />
                        @Html.TextAreaFor(model => model.Description, new { style = "width:95%;min-height:80px;" })
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="h-double">
                    <div class="editor-label">
                        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.RequestedBy)
                    </div>
                    <div class="editor-field">
                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.RequestedBy)<br />
                        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.RequestedBy)
                    </div>

                    <div class="editor-label">
                        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.JobTitle)
                    </div>
                    <div class="editor-field">
                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.JobTitle)<br />
                        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.JobTitle)
                    </div>

                    <div class="editor-label">
                        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.LocalOfficeOrTeam)
                    </div>
                    <div class="editor-field">
                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.LocalOfficeOrTeam)<br />
                        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.LocalOfficeOrTeam)
                    </div>

                    <div class="editor-label">
                        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.SiteVisit)
                    </div>
                    <div class="editor-field">
                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.SiteVisit)<br />
                        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.SiteVisit)
                    </div>

                    <div class="editor-label">
                        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.StatusID)
                    </div>
                    <div class="editor-field">
                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.StatusID)<br />
                        @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.StatusID, (IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)ViewBag.StatusID, "", null)
                    </div>

                    <div class="editor-label">
                        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.ConsultantRetained)
                    </div>
                    <div class="editor-field">
                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.ConsultantRetained)<br />
                        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.ConsultantRetained)
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="h-single">
                    <div class="editor-label">
                        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Comments)
                    </div>
                    <div class="editor-field">
                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Comments)<br />
                        @Html.TextAreaFor(model => model.Comments, new { style = "width:95%;min-height:80px;" })
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </fieldset>
    }
</form>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('.datepickerfield').each(function () {
            $(this).datepicker({ dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yy' });
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: You are applying metadata to your metadata class. Can you put the `MetadataType` on `BCRTAdvisoryRequest` and try that?

Comment: Post that as your answer, that was easier than expected ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apply `MetadataType` above the type that you want to apply metadata to, not the metadata class itself.

```
public partial class BCRTAdvisoryRequest
{
    [MetadataType(typeof(BCRTAdvisoryRequest.MetaData))]
    public sealed class MetaData
    {
```

becomes...

```
[MetadataType(typeof(BCRTAdvisoryRequest.MetaData))]
public partial class BCRTAdvisoryRequest
{

    public sealed class MetaData
    {
```